# Triangle and its circumcircle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $\Gamma$ its circumcircle. On sides $AC$, $BC$ lies respectively points $E$, $F$ such that $CE=BE$ and $CF=AF$. $CM$ is a median of triangle $EFC$. Show that line $CM$ pass throught point $K$ which is point where meets tangents to circle $\Gamma$ at points $A, B$.

Here is my sketch, I know that $E, F, A, B$ lies on a common circle because triangle $EFC$ and $ABC$ are similar, but don't know what to do now.

[image]

Comment: Your diagram has the line CM going through a 4th point, the intersection of EB and AF.

Comment: @zyx: Of course, you should never trust a diagram. In this case, the figure is misleadingly symmetric. If you look at (and decide to trust) the figures accompanying my answer, you'll see that $\overline{CM}$ doesn't necessarily concur with $\overline{EB}$ and $\overline{AF}$. (I broke the symmetry on purpose.)

Comment: @Blue, thanks, that answers the implied question.

Answer (score 3):

Because $\triangle AFC$ and $\triangle BEC$ are isosceles, we have
$$\angle C \cong \angle CAF \cong CBE$$

[image]

(Note that $\angle C$ is necessarily acute.) Moreover, the bisectors of $\angle AEB$ and $\angle BFA$ create *four more* copies of $\angle C$. That two of these copies are $\angle HEA$ and $\angle HFB$ implies that $\square HEFC$ is a parallelogram, the diagonals of which bisect each other. Thus, $\overline{CH}$ passes through $M$.

[image]

It remains to show that $H$ coincides with $K$.

Note that $\angle EHF$ is *yet another* copy of $\angle C$ (as the opposite angle in the parallelogram). Since $\angle EAF$ and $\angle EBF$ are too, the points $H$, $A$, $B$ are concyclic with $E$ and $F$ (because they subtend the same angle with chord $\overline{EF}$).

[image]

This implies that $\angle ABH$ (which must be congruent to $\angle AFH$, as both subtend chord $\overline{AH}$) is also a copy of $\angle C$; likewise, $\angle BAH \cong \angle C$.

[image]

We see, then, that $H$ is the apex of the[*] isosceles triangle with base segment $\overline{AB}$ and base angles congruent to $\angle C$. This description also fits $K$ (why?), so the points must coincide.

[image]

---

[*] There are, of course, *two* such isosceles triangles with base $\overline{AB}$. "The" triangle in question is the one on the opposite side of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ from $C$. (Note that $\angle C$'s acuteness is key to making this distinction.)

Answer (score 1):

(These are complete steps, you just need to fill in the minor details.)

**Step 1:** Show that $AEFBK$ is con cyclic, as drawn in your diagram. It could be easier to show that $O$, the center of $\Gamma$, also lies on this circle.

**Step 2:** Show that $EF=KB=KA$, because they each subtend the same angle in this circle.

**Step 3:** Show that $KE \parallel BF$ and $KF \parallel EA$.

**Step 4:** Hence show that $KECF$ is a parallelogram.

Hence $CK$ bisects $EF$, so $CKM$ is a straight line.